# Torch: tensor to numpy - cycling problem .cpu() to .detach().numpy()

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, torch

I got a problem with converting a torch tensor to numpy array.

```
    avg_rewards = th.mean(rewards, dim=[0,1,3])
    avg_targets = th.mean(th.mean(targets.reshape(rewards.shape), dim=[0, 1, 3]))
    avg_score = th.max(avg_rewards, avg_targets)
    avg_q = th.mean(q, dim=[0, 1, 3])

    griefers = avg_score > avg_q
    griefers = [i for i, x in enumerate(griefers) if x]

    grieve_factor = th.tanh(th.clamp(avg_score / avg_q, min=0)).detach().numpy()
```

The last line returns an error. If I use `.detach().numpy()` I get "use .cpu()..." message.
If I however use `.cpu()` I get the "use `.detach().numpy()`" error

I printed out the type of grieve_factor:

```
the grieve factors are tensor([0., 0.], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<TanhBackward0>)
```

I don't need any gradients on it, and I just want it to be [0., 0.] array

Comment: Could you try ```.detach().cpu()``` ? Or ```.detach().cpu().numpy()```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`Tensor.numpy()` only performs the conversion if the tensor is on the CPU](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.numpy.html#torch-tensor-numpy). Since your tensor is on a GPU, you should either move it to the CPU before the conversion as hinted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837095/torch-tensor-to-numpy-cycling-problem-cpu-to-detach-numpy#comment132073119_74837095) or by setting `force=True`:

```py
grieve_factor = th.tanh(th.clamp(avg_score / avg_q, min=0)).numpy(force=True)
```